# SQL Server paging query with random result that inserted each page

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Ok, let's say I have table with 3 col (`card_no`, `email`, `trans_date`)

I want to write a query to get paging with random email domain each page, can somebody help me? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and for temporary I use this query

```
WITH CTEResults AS 
(
    SELECT 
        card_no,
        Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY trans_date DESC) AS RowNum,
        email,
        Substring(email, Charindex('@', email), Len(email)) AS Domain
    FROM   
        kartu
)
SELECT *
FROM CTEResults
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 200
```

I hope somebody can help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you want random order, you need to store the paginated result somewhere to make sure same results are not brought back again

```
If object_id('tempdb.dbo.#kartu') is null
select * into #kartu from kartu where 1 = 0

;WITH CTEResults
     AS (SELECT card_no,
                Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY new_id()) AS RowNum,
                email,
                Substring(email, Charindex('@', email), Len(email)) AS Domain
         FROM   kartu a
         Where not exists (select 1 from #kartu b where a.card_no = b.card_no and a.email = b.email))
Insert into #kartu output inserted.*
SELECT *
FROM   CTEResults
WHERE  RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 200
```

Comment: vary thank's, that's good answer but inserted output not 200, actually i want send email notification with paging data, i don't want that email landing on spam, so i don't send email with same domain continuesly and i want split email addres with same domain  into each page